# NgRx EntityState - Can we use EntityState on a state object property

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-entity

Continuing with my new journey into `NgRx`, I just discovered `EntityState`, and if I am understanding, and trying to use it correctly, it covers all the "collection manipulation" operations I need to do for me!

I have followed this [excellent tutorial](https://blog.angular-university.io/ngrx-entity/), with the one small difference where I want to (if it is possible) to use an `EntityState` for a property of my state object, as opposed to extending it to be the whole state object, as in the linked example). I have done this to match my existing data, and to allow perhaps another list property that is also a `EntityState` (once again if it can be used this way).

I have replaced what was an array of objects in one of my feature state objects, but having trouble with a select.

I have a simple version of this [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrxrootstate-nested).

Following this example, the state is for **feature1**, which for simplicity I have just put into a folder rather than a separate module.

My application has existing classes where I serialise in data from the server.

I have put these into the freature1.reducers.ts file..

```
 export class BookModel {
      public id : string;
      public title: string;
    }

 /** Serialised in from the backend */
 export class LibraryBackendModel {
      books: Array<BookModel>;
    }
```

So I declare interfaces for the state I want to store, and it is this `Array<BookModel>` I hope I can replace with `EntityState`

So, the feature state, I have the following (in the same file)...

```
export interface LibraryState {
  isOpen : boolean,
  books: EntityState<BookModel> // <----- now using EntityState instead of an array

  // Maybe other collections to come
}
```

I have a single action `getLibrarySuccess` which is triggered when new data comes in from the server, and in the reducer file, I use the helper method `updateBookList` which will use all the various methods on the `EntityAdapter` to do updates (not included, but thats where they would be).

So far, everything seems fine..

Now finally, (**where the problem is**) is in `feature1.component.ts`, where I want to subscribe to the selector `getAllBooks`

```
 this.store.pipe(select(fromLibrary.getAllBooks),
      ).subscribe(
        books => this.libaryModel.books = books
      );
```

Here, I can see the IDE reporting a problem:

[image]

The error being....

```
Type '(state: EntityState<BookModel>) => BookModel[]' is not assignable to type 'BookModel[]'.
```

So, it appears there is something wrong with my selector...

```
export const getAllBooks = createSelector(
   getFeature1State,
   state => fromFeature1.getBooks
 );
```

But I am not sure how to fix this, of what I am doing wrong. The `fromFeature1.getBooks` is a reference to the `booksAdapter.getSelectors().selectAll;` from the `EntityAdapter`. I am assuming I need to somehow use a selector from this `EntityAdapter` to get my updates and state, but I am just not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem, I just needed to pass in the `state.books` as below...

```
export const getAllBooks = createSelector(
   getFeature1State,
   state => fromFeature1.getBooks(state.books) <--- pass in state.books
);
```